# Counting straight lines

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of straight lines that go through at least two points of a $10$ by $10$ grid of points?
Label the points in the grid $A_1, A_2, \dots A_{10}, B_1, B_2,\dots, B_{10},\dots ,J_1, J_2, ..., J_{10}$.

The number of straight lines passing through the origin $A_1$ = $1$ vertical $+$ $1$ horizontal $+$ $9$[Row$_2$] $+$ $9$[Row$_3$] $+ \ldots +9$[Row$_{10}$] $ = 83$.

The number of new straight lines passing through $A_2$ = $1$ horizontal + $9$[Row$_1$] $+9$[Row$_3$]$ + 9$[Row$_4$]$ + \ldots + 9$[Row$_{10}$] $= 82$.

Similar calculations for the rest of the $A_j$ yields the total
of $83 + 9 \cdot 82 = 9585$.

I hope someone can confirm that this is correct or explain the right answer.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to downvote this interesting question, which moreover shows a serious work. Can the downvoter express him/herself ? [+1] for countervote.

Comment: Suppose your grid is evenly laid, then the line through A1B2 is the same as through A1C3, hence you counted some several times. You could try the inclusion exclusion principle here (with no. of points on line). Also you forgot some lines not passing through points in the first row. **edit**: nice question by the way

Comment: By considering diagonal lines for each point $A_1,A_2......A_{10}$ i found an answer : $(2+9*9-8)*10=750$
I also generalized (tried to generalize) it for $n*n$ grid as,
$$
n((n-1)^2+2-(n-2))=n^3-3n^2+5n
$$

Comment: @Bananabean: **In question,**  $9585$ should be $821$ ( $83+9*82$ is $821$ ).........